# No module named 'twilio'

Tags: twilio, anaconda3

I am trying to use twilio to send a text message...when I put the demo script in a texteditor, ave it as something.py and run it from terminal, I receive the text message.

However, when I copy and paste the same code into Spyder (Anaconda 3 environment, Python 3.8) I get the following error.

**Here is the code:**

```
    from twilio.rest import Client
    
    account_sid = 'xxx'
    auth_token = 'xxx'
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    
    message = client.messages \
                    .create(
                         body="Test.",
                         from_='x',
                         to='xxx'
                     )

print(message.sid)
```

**And here is there error:**

```
  File "xxx", line 14, in <module>
    import twilio

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio'
```

I have installed with pip, pip3, Conda, all that.

I'm not really used to this anaconda environment thing, but when I search for the package "twilio" the only thing that shows up is r-Twilio. I imagine this is something to do with the problem, but I've no idea. I tried creating a new environment with python 2.7 and again only saw the r-twilio thing.

Comment: Try https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/issues/412

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that before posting here but didn’t resolve the issue.